# What is a RESTful style resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, cancan

I'm implementing cancan into my Rails 4 app.  The documentation states "load_and_authorize_resource method is provided to automatically authorize all actions in a RESTful style resource controller."

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan

What is a RESTful style?

Thank you.

Comment: You usually get a better response if you at least attempt to do some research before asking questions. You can start by reading about [representational state transfer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) and [routing in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a list of them [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1671632&seqNum=11%20here).

The actions specifically are index, new, show, edit, destroy, create, update.  The idea is there is a lot of boilerplate in general for these actions (find/authorize) and this aims to simplify that.